# How to get and set pixel's color value using graphics.py in python3

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

I'm implementing Boundary Fill Algorithm for polygons in python.How to get and set the color of a pixel?
I'm using graphics.py file.

Comment: is this the graphics.py you are using? http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Comment: Yes.This is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zelle graphics provides operators to manipulate pixels of images as documented in the code:

> The library also provides a very simple class for pixel-based image
>   manipulation, Pixmap. A pixmap can be loaded from a file and displayed
>   using an Image object. Both getPixel and setPixel methods are provided
>   for manipulating the image.

But not higher level objects like polygons.

This answer to [Get color of coordinate of figure drawn with Python Zelle graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52773485/5771269) shows how to *get* the fill color of an object like a polygon located at a given (x, y) coordinate using the tkinter underpinnings of Zelle graphics.  I doubt this technique can be used to *set* the color of a pixel of a polygon, however.